# Proper use of commas

Tags: punctuation

Where should commas be inserted?

> In 2000 my future boss Bill Smith had a vision to build the tallest
>   building in New York.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, a prepositional phrase that starts a sentence is set off by a comma:

> Only a few miles from work, I decided to return home.

However, it is common to omit that comma if the phrase is only a few words long (fewer than four, say).

For your sentence, you have to decide what the *subject* is.  Is it "my future boss" (who happens to be named Bill Smith) or is it "Bill Smith" (who happens to be my future boss)?

In the former case, "Bill Smith" is an [appositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) and should be set off by commas.

> In 2000 my future boss, Bill Smith, had a vision to build the tallest building in New York.

In the latter "my future boss" is effectively a title, little different than "Mr."

> In 2000 my future boss Bill Smith had a vision to build the tallest building in New York.

The choice depends on exactly what you want to say.

Consider this sentence:

> In 1971 Jerry Baldwin, Zev Siegl, and Gordon Bowker opened the first Starbucks, in Seattle.

Note that the final prepositional phrase is *non-restrictive*.  That "first Starbucks" was the first Starbucks anywhere; it just happened to be in Seattle.  Because the phrase is non-restrictive -- because it is effectively parenthetical and could be removed without greatly affecting the meaning of the sentence -- it is set off by a comma. Compare it to

> In 2015 CEO Troy Alstead opened the first Starbucks in Azerbaijan.

Here the phrase is restrictive.  That "first Starbucks" was only the first Starbucks in Azerbaijan.  If you dropped the phrase, the sentence would become altogether false.  Therefore, no comma.

In your sentence, "in New York" is restrictive (I assume: it would be odd to say "tallest building" utterly without qualification).  If you wrote

> Bill Smith had a vision to build the world's tallest building in New York.

the absence of the comma makes the sentence seems almost paradoxical, perhaps humorously so.  "The world's tallest building in New York?  As opposed to the world's tallest building in Albuquerque?"*

Putting the comma in

> Bill Smith had a vision to build the world's tallest building, in New York.

makes your meaning clear: he wanted to build the world's tallest building and he wanted to build it in New York.

---

* Someone should investigate why a few city names -- Walla-Walla, Dubuque, Pismo Beach, Sheboygan, and of course Albuquerque -- are inherently funny, while the rest are not.  If the explanation could be reduced to a single simple rule, we could call it [the Tex Avery Principle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8TUwHTfOOU).

Comment: I dunno, I sort of disagree with some of your non-restrictive classifications. It depends on what the writer meant. Did Bill Smith specifically set out to build the world's tallest building in New York and no other city, or did he simply want to build the tallest building ever and it happened to be built in New York? Depending on which it is, you either have a restrictive or non-restrictive phrase

Answer (score 1):

The *subordinate* phrase goes inside a pair of commas (or brackets). This is a question of the priorities of the author:

If the most important statement is

> In 2000 my future boss had a vision to build the tallest building in
>   New York,

Then you punctuate like this: "In 2000 my future boss, Bill Smith, had a vision to build the tallest building in New York." (Subordinating Bill Smith)

If the most important statement is

> In 2000 Bill Smith had a vision to build the tallest building in New
>   York,

Then you punctuate like this: "In 2000 Bill Smith, my future boss, had a vision to build the tallest building in New York."(subordinating 'my future boss.')

[Generally speaking, punctuate as lightly as possible, and punctuate to mark pauses, if you want to be trendy.]